# Angular pipe not working on updating values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

I am facing issues with angular pipe.
I am building an application using reactive forms that perform calculation and display cost.
When it is calculated for first time then it displays currency pipe but when i again calculate it and if the result cost comes same then currency pipe is not displayed instead it shows only number.It works fine if the cost changes everytime.

```
 <input type="text"   [value]="AccountingForm.get('Cost').value |currency:'USD'"
                                formControlName="Cost"  class="form-control">
```

For example when i calculate , it shows $100.00 and when i again calculate it and cost remain same then it shows 100 without currency pipe.

in calculate method i am setting like this

```
 this.AccountingForm.controls['Cost'].setValue(value);
```

Comment: Seems fine to me can you please share more details or your more code and check if there are some errors in console 
Maybe your value is a string that is why it is not letting that pipe work

Comment: @MaBbKhawaja there are no error in console also value is not string.

Answer (score 3):

Make your pipe impure to resolve it. Include pure false in your pipe decorator.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'flyingHeroesImpure',
  pure: false
})
```

Comment: Since he is using the Angular `Currency Pipe` he is not able to set the pipe to impure. Also setting a pipe to impure can have a large impact on the performance because the pipe will be executed in **every** change detection cycle (see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#impure-pipes)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pipe, try to implement the same thing in your ts file